# First section link in the FAQ is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, faq-page

The "What kind of questions can I ask here?" link in the right navbar on the main [FAQ](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq) page is broken for me. Its causing a JavaScript error when clicked.

[image]

Comment: I just checked on another SE site, and it seems to be localized to this site.

Comment: Confirmed. I was able to reproduce this. I didn't get the JavaScript failure, but the link does nothing on my end — we'll provide an updated status once the dev team can investigate further.

Comment: Voted to close to indicate that this is no longer a live issue. See http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1142/70

Comment: It's still broken for me.

Comment: @Nick Still broken.

Comment: @Luke - I found the problem, looks like a bad version of the default FAQ got used...it'll be fixed next build everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I note this has now been fixed, but I can't retag as `Status Completed` as I'm not a moderator.